# How to rename a CSV column header after importing with 'DictReader'?

Tags: python, string

The following code is from the Udacity course "Intro to Data Analysis". See GitHub repository [udacity-course/intro_to_data_analysis](https://github.com/tuanavu/udacity-course/tree/master/intro_to_data_analysis).

### Read in the data from daily_engagement.csv

```python
import unicodecsv

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fun:
        reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(fun)
        return list(reader)
    
daily_engagement = read_csv("daily_engagement.csv")
print(daily_engagement[0])
```

#### Output

```
{'acct': '0', 'utc_date': '2015-01-09', 'num_courses_visited': '1.0', 'total_minutes_visited': '11.6793745', 'lessons_completed': '0.0', 'projects_completed': '0.0'}
```

### Rename the "acct" column in the daily_engagement table to "account_key"

```python
for daily in daily_engagement: 
    for key in daily.keys():
        key.replace('acct','account_key')
        print(daily_engagement[0])
```

#### Output

```
{'acct': '0', 'utc_date': '2015-01-09', 'num_courses_visited': '1.0', 'total_minutes_visited': '11.6793745', 'lessons_completed': '0.0', 'projects_completed': '0.0'}
...
```

But for some reason the "acct" column is not renamed.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: quick guess: `key.replace(...)` returns the new value you want, it does not modify the stored value

Answer (score 1):

With `key.replace('acct','account_key')`, you just create a new string from the `key` with the text replaced (which may include `acct` as a substring of other keys), but this does not actually change the String associated with `key` but create a new string (which is then never used as you do not assign it to a variable), and thus does not change the key in the dictionary.

Instead, you have to insert a new key into the dictionary and remove the old one. The `pop` method removes the specified key from the dictionary and returns the value, so we can use that.

```
for daily in daily_engagement:
    daily['account_key'] = daily.pop('acct')
```